# Using args or props to derive data from Redux using selectors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

**TL;DR**: *I'm trying to use an id and type parameters in my selectors but the params are `undefined`. What is the correct way of doing this using `reselect` and `createStructuredSelector`?*

I'm writing selectors using `reselect` to get the data needed for a React component. The data is stored in a key/value format where the key is made up of a **dynamic id and type value**. The object looks like this:

```
customView: {
    'viewBy:deviceProfileId&id:5923f82a-80c2-4c88-bd0e-c105ad989ab2': { // type = 'deviceProfileId' & id = '5923f82a-80c2-4c88-bd0e-c105ad989ab2'
        list: { ... },
        meta: { ... }, 
        error: { ... }
     }
```

Users enter the id and type and trigger the data fetching from API. I have the basic selector but I'm stuck trying to get the data needed for each entry using these dynamic values - they continue to come out undefined. What am I missing? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
// reducer.js : Fn to generate key
export const customViewKey = ({ customViewType, id } = {}) => {
  const typeKey = (customViewType && `viewBy:${customViewType}`) || '';
  const idKey = (id && `id:${id}`) || '';
  const namespace = `${typeKey}&${idKey}`;
  return `${namespace}`;
};

// selector.js
const getCustomView = ({ customView }) => customView; // Basic selector works

export const getCustomViewData = createSelector(
  getCustomView,
  (customView, id, customViewType) => { // id and customViewType are undefined
    return customView && customView[customViewKey({ customViewType, id })];
  }
);

// index.js 
export const CustomViewsPage = ({ classes, getCustomView, customViewMap, customViewType, id }) => {  
  const [idValue, setIdValue] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState('');

  const handleTypeChange = (e) => {
    let typeEntered = e ? e.value : '';
    setType(typeEntered);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setIdValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => { // Fn called when user hits submit 
    e.preventDefault();
    getCustomView({ id: idValue, customViewType: type });
  };

return (
    <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.customViewForm}>
                <div>
                  <p>Select type of custom view:</p>
                  <Select
                    placeholder="View messages by"
                    options={customViewTypes}
                    onChange={handleTypeChange}
                    isClearable
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p>Enter ID for device, project or device profile:</p>
                  <InputBase
                    placeholder="5923f82a-80c2-4c88-bd0e-c105ad989ab2"
                    required
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="create-custom-view-btn">
                  <Input id="create-custom-view-btn" type="submit" />
                  <Button
                    component="span"
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    endIcon={<SendRounded />}
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                  >
                    Create view
                  </Button>
                </label>
            </form>

</div>

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getCustomView: requestCustomView,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  customViewMap: getCustomViewMap,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CustomViewsPage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution thanks to @markerikson's answer and this [blog](https://flufd.github.io/reselect-with-multiple-parameters/).

These are the selectors I'm using:

```
const getCustomView = ({ customView }) => customView;

const getId = (_, id) => id;

const getCustomViewType = (_, id, customViewType) => customViewType;

export const getCustomViewData = createSelector(
  getCustomView,
  getId,
  getCustomViewType,
  (customView, id, customViewType) => {
    return customView && customView[customViewKey({ customViewType, id })]; // WORKS!
  }
);

export const getCustomViewMap = createSelector(getCustomViewData, getDomainMap);
```

And I'm using `useSelector` to call the selector from my component this way:

```
const selectedCustomView = useSelector(state => getCustomViewMap(state, idValue, type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your `createSelector` call is wrong.

If you want your "output function" to take 3 arguments, then you need to write 3 separate "input functions".  Each input function should extract and return a value, and those become the arguments for the output function.

So, you need something like this:

```
export const getCustomViewData = createSelector(
  getCustomView,
  // these should also read values from `state` or any other args
  getId,
  getCustomViewType,
  (customView, id, customViewType) => {
    // return calculation results here
  }
);
```

See the Redux docs [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) usage guide page for more details on how to use Reselect.

Comment: Thanks @markerikson. I have a better understanding now of the purpose of "output" and "input" functions. I am still having trouble figuring out the best way to the `id` and `type` values to the selector functions. They're currently declared within the `CustomViewsPage` and are changed based on user input. What is the best way to pass the current value of these as args to the selectors? Or would it be better to store them in state?

Comment: You can pass arbitrary arguments to any selector, like `selectSomeThing(state, "a", 42, someOtherVariable)` - you just need to write "input functions" that forward those to the output function.  See the docs page I linked for examples.